# У меня не работает Django код, что делать

Tags: python, django

После того как я написал код для первого элемента в приложении он у меня заработал, а когда я написал 2-ой,код перестал работать. Я чуть ниже оставлю именно неработающий:
В urls.py (в приложении):

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index)
    path('about', views.about)#Я так понял, что cmd ругается именно на эту строку
 ]

В views.py:

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'main/index.html')


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'main/syth.html')
```

А вот сама ошибка:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x03B1AE88>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique

    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 540, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 533, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\python\django\newproject\newproject\urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    path('', include('main.urls'))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1467, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1572, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\python\django\newproject\main\urls.py", line 6
    path('about', views.about)
```

Answer (score 0):

запятую пропустил при перечислении

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index) #<<<тут надо запятая так как это список
    path('about', views.about)#Я так понял, что cmd ругается именно на эту строку
 ]
```

Comment: спасибо, теперь работает